# $R_{n,n}$ isomorphic to opposite ring

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

I'd like to show that $(R_{n,n}, +_{r}, \cdot$) is isomorphic to the opposite ring $(R^{opp}_{n,n},+_{opp}, *)$ for $n>1$.
I have a proof and I think the idea is right, however I'm struggling a bit to actually write it down correctly.

My idea: Define $\phi: R_{n,n}\rightarrow R^{opp}_{n,n}$ with $\phi(A)=A^T$.

Clearly, $\phi$ is a bijection since

$\phi^{-1} (\phi(A))=\phi^{-1}(A^T)=(A^T)^T=A$.

Same for $\phi(\phi^{-1}(A))$.

Then we also have that

$\phi(A+_rB) = (A+_{opp}B)^T = A^T+_{opp}B^T
=\phi(A)+_{opp}\phi(B)$ and

$\phi(A \cdot B) = (A\cdot B)^T=B^T \cdot A^T = A^T * B^T = \phi(A) * \phi(B)$.
Hence, $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Is that correct? I am a little unsure when to use $+_r$ and $+_{opp}$ and when $\cdot$ and $*$   respectively. Can someone help out?

Comment: What is $R_{n,n}$?

Comment: The matrix ring with matrices with the dimension $n \times n$. Sorry, I should have  added that to my question.

Comment: So $M_n(R_{n,n})$ is then matrices with matrix entries??

Comment: Yes, we have matrices  of the dimension $n \times n$ with entries from the ring $R$.

Comment: You are mixing the two notations. Either use your weird notation $R_{n,n}$, or the standard notation $M_n(R)$, but not both at the same time.

Comment: Okay sorry, the notation $R_{n,n}$ was used in my lecture. I've edited it now.

Comment: Is my proof correct though?